# How to properly add single route to existing route resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want to properly add new route to already existing route resources in `Spree`.

Desired end url format: `/orders/:order_id/order_returns(.:format)`

I can achieve this by adding following snippet to `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :orders, only: [] do
   resources :order_returns, controller: 'order_returns', only: [:create]
 end
end
```

but `resources :orders, only: [] do` looks kind of ugly with empty hash and if I remove it `Rails` will generate routes for `orders` :(

Is there a better, `Rails`/`Spree` way to achieve that ?

Comment: You don't need any routes for orders? Even Show or Index?

Comment: @RoccoBasso routes for orders are already created by Spree so I don't need them. I'm thinking of using namespace or scope instead of resources, unless somebody post other solution.